# Is it possible to send a toast and badge notification in a single push message - windows WNS

Tags: windows, azure, push-notification, toast, wns

Is it possible to send both a badge and toast notification in a single message.

The XML schema for a badge is

```
<badge value="attention"/>
```

The XML schema for a toast is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<toast>
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastText01">
            <text id="1">Test message</text>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
```

Is it possible to combine these in a single message so that the badge gets updated and the toast is displayed?